# Pluralbildung von Musketier und Rentier

Tags: etymology, noun, grammatical-number

Wie kommt es, dass Musketier ausgesprochen und gesteigert wird (Musketiere), als würde es sich tatsächlich um ein Tier handeln, während Rentier (Person, die von regelmäßigen Zahlungen aus in Obligationen angelegtem Kapital oder der Verpachtung von Land lebt) seine französische Aussprache behält und als Rentiers gesteigert wird?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erklärungsversuch (mehr Vermutung): Die verschiedenen Bezeichnungen der Waffengattungen (Musketier, Kanonier, Pikenier etc) wurden wahrscheinlich viel früher in die deutsche Sprache übernommen als der Begriff "Rentier" in der Bedeutung als Bezeichnung für eine Person (im Grimm ist "Rentier" in keiner der beiden Bedeutungen nachgewiesen). Außerdem gehört "Rentier" m.E. zu einer eher höheren Sprachebene, die sich eher dadurch auszeichnet, dass die fremdsprachige Flexion nach Möglichkeit beibehalten wird.

EDIT: Nach etwas Stöbern in der [rückläufig sortierten OWID-Stichwortliste](http://www.owid.de/pls/db/p4_suche_elex.Stichw_alpha_rueck) sind mir selber Zweifel gekommen. Es läuft auf zwei Gruppen von Substantiven hinaus (wenn man mal Substantive wie "`Belgier`" und "`Georgier`", die von einem Staatsnamen auf -ien abhängen, außen vor lässt):

- **französische Aussprache und Flexion (Fremdwörter)**: `Romancier`, `Conférencier`, `Portier`, `Bankier`, `Rentier`, `Privatier`, `Sommelier`, `Hotelier`, `Premier`, `Routinier`: Sprachebene?
- **deutsche Aussprache (Lehnwörter?)**: `Musketier` etc., aber auch `Pionier`, `Passagier`, `Barbier`, `Juwelier`, `Kavalier`.

Juwelier, Passagier und Kavalier scheinen mir der Argumentation mit dem Alter zu widersprechen. Ein richtig klares Bild gibt das leider nicht.

EDIT 2: Interessanterweise führt [Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=passagier) für "`Passagier`" sowohl die deutsche als auch die französische Pluralform - mit Verweis auf Schiller, Die Räuber, 2. Akt, 3. Szene:

> **Razmann.** Wer da? was gibts da? Passagiers im Wald?

Comment: Beide Vermutungen (Waffengattungen und höhere Sprachebene) klingen recht plausibel.

Comment: Nach deiner Bearbeitung: Ich fürchte, eine allgemeingültige Regel wirst du nicht finden. Es gibt keine Regeln, die bestimmen, wann oder wie ein Fremdwort "eingedeutscht" wird. Es passiert einfach ;)

Answer (score 5):

Wenn Rentier gesprochen und flektiert würde wie Musketier, gäbe es natürlich auch eine massive Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem gleichnamigen Tier. Möglicherweise hat sich dadurch die komplette Beibehaltung der französischen Form ergeben.

Auf der anderen Seite wird die Muskete natürlich auch nicht französisch ausgesprochen, so dass die Endung automatisch ebenfalls wie im Deutschen ausgesprochen wird, weil man die Sprachen ungern im selben Wort mischt.

Comment: Mir ist gerade aufgefallen, dass Rentier eigentlich gar nicht komplett französisch ausgesprochen wird, sonst müsste ja da "Ren-" klingen wie in "Rendevous" ... vielleicht wurde hier tatsächlich nur die Aussprache der Endung beibehalten, damit keine Verwechslung mit dem Tier entsteht?

Comment: Was die Verwechselungsgefahr betrifft, halte ich "`Rentier`" aber für einen Sonderfall. In den anderen Fällen von Substantiven auf -ier besteht sie nicht, trotzdem ist die französische Aussprache beibehalten. Und streng genommen könnte man "`Rentíer`" und "`Réntier`" aufgrund der Betonung unterscheiden: parallel zu "Barbíer" würde man "Rentíer" wohl auf der zweiten Silbe betonen, das Tier wird jedoch auf der ersten Silbe betont.

Comment: Endlich erwähnt jemand die schönen [Rentiere](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren) die den Weihnachtsmann zu den Kindern bringen.